# How to Mathematica applied discrete Fourier transform to matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, fourier-analysis

I am new user of Mathematica, sorry if my question odd.

I not understanding, how to Mathematica apply the discrete Fourier transform for matrix:

```
Print[Fourier[{{-50, 50}, {50, 50}, {50, -50}}]];
(*Result is:
{{40.8248 +0. I,0. +0. I},
{-20.4124+35.3553 I,-61.2372-35.3553 I},
{-20.4124-35.3553 I,-61.2372+35.3553 I}}
*)
```

Can you explain the step-by-step execution of this program using only `Fourier` for 1-d lists?

Comment: Check out [Fourier](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) in the docs. You may also want to look into a tutorial for new users - [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) is a good resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fourier` does a 2D discrete Fourier transform.

You can decompose this into the individual 1D transforms using the techniques illustrated in the following example:

```
M = {{-50, 50}, {50, 50}, {50, -50}};
Transpose[Fourier /@ Transpose[Fourier /@ M]] == Fourier[M]
(* True *)
```